How to index a TEXT column containing non-English text for partial matches?
I am attempting to index a TEXT column that contains Korean characters. I am using a select query that uses LIKE for partial matching.
Example:
SELECT name_en, name_kr FROM table_name WHERE name_kr LIKE '%쿠키%'

Is it possible to do this with PostGreSQL? If not, what relational database is capable of doing it?

Is it that you want something more than character-based (unicode codepoint) matching, or are you saying that doesn't work? Because this gives true for me: SELECT 'xx쿠키xx' LIKE '%쿠키%';

The query works, but it can't be indexed effectively in pg_trgm because the pattern contains no usable trigrams, just like '%ab%' doesn't .
